# "In the middle of riddle" means what?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

There is a song whose lyrics is given below... Can anyone tell what exactly "in the middle of riddle" means?

> At the edge of the moon there's
>   a lonely man
>   And he blows on his horn as
>   strong as he can
>
> And the girl at the bar wipoes the breath
>   of winter away with a smile of her face
>   And a little black dog barks along
>   with a loon
>
> Is this my appointment or did I came
>   too soon
>   Got a strange invitation for teatime 'twas
>   given by somebody
>   I can't recall
>   It's **the middle of the riddle**
>   It's not very serious
>   It's nothing but a big surprise
>
> And the president's horse is a rabbit
>   of course
>   That is livin' in a big boy's mind
>   Livin' in a big boy's mind
>
> And I skate on a knife on a wire
>   That is strung from this song
>   to a distant shore
>
> And then I say
>   Intuition is just another phase of chance
>   While we're walking the old
>   pyramid's floors 
>   (Little pharaoh's)
>   And the little black dog
>   Here it comes again
>   He's a true companion in a foreign land
>
> On a quest for the valley of boojums and birthdays
>   And phone calls I cannot recall
>   It's **the middle of the riddle**
>   It's not very serious
>   It's nothing but a big surprise
>
> And the president's horse is a rabbit

Comment: Please see a add also :http://www.mindinsight.com/quizarena.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The middle of the riddle* is not an established English phrase, so your guess is as good as anyone's as to what it means here

I suggest the main thing it means is the guy who wrote the lyrics for this Alphaville song knows how to create a rhyme.

Please don't ask what *the president's horse is a rabbit* means. The answer to that is also "not much".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Requesting you to please see the link:http://www.mindinsight.com/quizarena.jsp

Comment: There is flash add regarding the phrase in the middle of riddle....

Comment: @prem shekhar: I still think *middle of the riddle* was penned primarily for its *sound* rather than meaning. The ad in your link omits the word *the* in this 'phrase'. And I note the site says you need *an open mind with good observations* to solve their puzzles, which really isn't a valid phrase at all. This suggests to me the site's creators aren't particularly fluent in English themselves. You will learn little from them.

Comment: Ok I also thought like that....I agree with you

Comment: @prem: Well said. If I'm correct in assuming your primary motivation here is to improve your English, at this stage I would avoid spending too much time on utterances where the phrasing is likely to influenced by 'artistic' considerations such as sound, semantic juxtaposition, and other 'word play'.

Comment: @prem: Having said that, if it's not too difficult you might learn things by studying the online *Guardian Crossword*, and the analysis thereof at http://fifteensquared.net/category/guardian/